# Autolayout not working - Child View Size always 0 while it should have same size as Superview

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I have an odd behaviour for NSView in regards to autolayout.

I am bounding my only child view to the superview's size by this code:

```
   func fillHorizontal() {
        guard let sv = self.superview else {
            assert(false)
            return
        }
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        sv.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: self, attribute: .width,
                relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sv,
                attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        sv.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: self, attribute: .left,
                relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sv,
                attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }

    func fillVertical() {
        guard let sv = self.superview else {
            assert(false)
            return
        }
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: self, attribute: .height,
                relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sv,
                attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        sv.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: self, attribute: .top,
                relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sv,
                attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }

    func bindFrameToSuperviewBounds() {
        fillHorizontal()
        fillVertical()
    }
```

The resulting constraints are as I would expect
[image]

However, I was never able to see the child view (GraphView). When started debugging/tweaking the setFrameSize function in child view like this:

```
override func setFrameSize(_ newSize: NSSize) {
    if let superSize = self.superview?.frame.size, newSize == superSize {  //this is quite dodgy. Not sure why I get too many zero-sized initiations.
        super.setFrameSize(newSize)
    }
}
```

then it became clear that all the layout engine is always calculating a size 0 for the child view.

[image]

How can that be? Who can tell me my mistake? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your superview positioned correctly and has a non zero width and height?

Comment: I am simply sometimes too dumb! I set the size of the outer NSView directly, instead of using constraints. Beginners mistake. @KamilSzostakowski: Your question triggered me finding my mistake. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Kamil Szostakowski asked the right question. Autolayout doesn't work well with manual size setting. I need to set NSView frame size through constraints. 
Thanks Kamil.

Comment: I'm glad that helped.